# Electric guitar is making a weird vibrating noise on hammer-on

Tags: electric-guitar, noise, resonance

I bought a new ESP LTD M-201 guitar and everything is sounding nice, except if I hammer-on in this specific spot in the guitar, it starts to vibrate and make a weird noise. I tried fretwrap and it helps to eliminate the noise as you can see in the video, but is there a way to fix problem like this, without using fretwrap?

You can check out the video I made of the problem here:
[Guitar vibration problem video](https://www.reddit.com/r/guitarrepair/comments/16g1qp9/electric_guitar_is_making_a_vibrating_noise_on/)

Comment: Drop the whole guitar a semitone or even tone, see if it affects 1) the same fret or 2) the same note. 1) would indicate a possible high fret, 2) would be something in sympathetic vibration, bridge spring etc.

Comment: You got your answer on reddit: mute the strings you are not playing.

Answer (score 1):

The hammered-on note is B. The note you are hammering on to is B. Maybe not exactly in tune with each other, but what's happening is the two B notes are sounding together. Try damping (muting) the B string alone. Probably the effect will disappear.

When using gain on a guitar, it's wise to get used to muting all other strings (using whatever you can - palm, fingers, of either hand). I expect the problem will not be there any more.

The 'oscillations' are most likely due to the two B notes not being exactly in tune with each other, causing what's known as 'beating'. Yes, I'm aware that the two notes are an octave apart, but the effect will still be there.